# BigQuery: Window Analytics Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

If i run the following query

```
WITH series AS(
  SELECT 'abcd' AS id, 'first' AS value, DATE('2020-07-27') AS date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abcd' AS id, 'second' AS value, DATE('2020-07-28') AS date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'efgh' AS id, 'first' AS value, DATE('2020-07-29') AS date
)

SELECT DISTINCT id, LAST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) AS value
FROM series
```

I expect to get the following two records, one for abcd/second and the other efgh/first but i got 3 rows:

[image]

Any ideas of that issue? This was working last week.

Thanks,

Philippe

Comment: tested with first_value and it's working.

Comment: If you found the solution, please consider posting it. If the solution was found on your already-posted answer, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Google:

> This is expected in SQL Standard. When there is ORDER BY clause in
> analytic function for FIRST_VALUE & LAST_VALUE, if the window range is
> not explicitly specified by user, it means "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED
> PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" by default. So the above query is
> equivalent to following:
>
> WITH series AS(  SELECT 'abcd' AS id, 'first' AS value,
> DATE('2020-07-27') AS date  UNION ALL  SELECT 'abcd' AS id, 'second'
> AS value, DATE('2020-07-28') AS date  UNION ALL  SELECT 'efgh' AS id,
> 'first' AS value, DATE('2020-07-29') AS date ) SELECT DISTINCT id,
> LAST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC RANGE
> BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS value FROM series;
>
> When using LAST_VALUE for first row (id='abcd' & value = 'first'),
> because the window range is UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW, there
> is only one row in that window so the LAST_VALUE returns 'first'. For
> second row (id='abcd' & value = 'second'), the LAST_VALUE returns
> 'second'. As a result, the first & second rows could not be grouped
> together by DISTINCT since the LAST_VALUE are different. That's why
> there are 3 rows as a result. When using FIRST_VALUE, the first row &
> second row returns the same FIRST_VALUE result 'first', then, they are
> deduped by DISTINCT so that only 2 rows left.

Here is a working solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, LAST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS value
FROM series
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(s ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM series s
GROUP BY id
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id      value   date     
1   abcd    second  2020-07-28   
2   efgh    first   2020-07-29
```